# how to swith to a branch without resolving the current branch conflicts?

Tags: git

I am on a branch, I pulled master, and merged it to my branch and I got a lot of conflicts, I want to not correct them now but move to an other branch now.

what I tried to do is to do a stash :

```
git stash
```

but there nothing to stash I think, so I stashed and did this :

```
git checkout mybranch
```

I get an error telling me, you have to resolve conflicts.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Force the checkout? `git checkout -f mybranch`. You'll lose unsaved changes though

Comment: This is the easiest thing to do, I just saw too much conflicts and did not change anything anyway, this is enough for me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to stop your current merge :

```
git merge --abort
```

You can always re-start the merge later on (merge conflicts included ! :) ) by running `git pull origin master` again.

Answer (score 1):

First cancel the ongoing merge with `git merge --abort`.

If checking out your branch is still not possible (if git detects that current changes would be overwritten by the check out operation), you'll have to wipe these changes first with `git stash` like you did.